# Webix remove columns from a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, webix

With Webix is there anyway to remove columns from a datatable? I have found the [webix datatable api documentation](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.datatable.html), but I can't find anything about removing a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. I was able to find a [sample that included the proper code](http://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/09_columns/04_add_column.html).

Relevant section:

```
var columns = webix.toArray(grid.config.columns);
columns.removeAt(2);
grid.refreshColumns();
```